# ASP.NET MVC ActionFilter - Determine if AJAX Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, action-filter

I am using an ActionFilter to determine if a user has access to a specific resource such as an Account object (a la Rhino Security) before hitting an action. This is a global filter which redirects to an error page should the authorization value fail

I'm using the following code, which works fine for full page requests:

```
filterContext.Controller.TempData["ErrorMessage"] = string.Format("You are not authorized to perform operation: {0}", operation);
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Error/AuthorizationError");
```

Ajax requests I do not want to apply a redirect, but rather return an error message. Is there a way to tell inside the action filter if this is an AJAX request or a regular full page (sorry not sure of the correct terminology) request?

Thanks in advance

JP

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use the [IsAjaxRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxrequestextensions.isajaxrequest.aspx) extension method:

```
if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    // it was an AJAX request
    ...
}
else
{
    // it was a standard request
    filterContext.Controller.TempData["ErrorMessage"] = string.Format("You are not authorized to perform operation: {0}", operation);
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Error/AuthorizationError");
}
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what we're trying to do.  But...for some reason that condition `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()` isn't coming back true when it's an AJAX request.  Also...how would you redirect the user to a new page from an ajax request?

Comment: @bubbleking I wish I had a good answer for you.  I can't even remember what page we were trying with this.  Sorry :(