# Determine if requester is an Ajax call and/or is expecting JSON (or another content type)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have solved a problem with a solution I found here on SO, but I am curious about if another idea I had is as bad as I think it might be.

I am debugging a custom security Attribute we have on/in several of our controllers.  The Attribute currently redirects unauthorized users using a RedirectResult.  This works fine except when calling the methods with Ajax.  In those cases, the error returned to our JS consists of a text string of all the HTML of our error page (the one we redirect to) as well as the HTTP code and text 200/OK.  I have solved this issue using the "IsAjaxRequest" method described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422191/asp-net-mvc-actionfilter-determine-if-ajax-request).  Now I am perfectly able to respond differently to Ajax calls.

Out of curiosity, however, I would like to know what pitfalls might exist if I were to instead have solved the issue by doing the following.  To me it seems like a bad idea, but I can't quite figure out why...

The `ActionExecutingContext` ("`filterContext`") has an `HttpContext`, which has a `Request`, which in turn has an `AcceptTypes` string collection.  I notice that on my Ajax calls, which expect JSON, the value of `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.AcceptTypes[0]` is "application/json."  I am wondering what might go wrong if I were to check this string against one or more expected content types and respond to them accordingly.  Would this work, or is it asking for disaster?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it works perfect, and I have been using that for years.

The whole point use request headers is to be able to tell the server what the client accept and expect.

I suggest you read more here about [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) and how it uses exactly that technique.

Comment: Well, then neat.  I'll keep that way in my back pocket too.  I was thinking it might be useful especially in cases where you're not simply expecting a page or a JSON response.  I did a decent amount of work with Web API a couple of years ago, but haven't had any projects on it lately.  I did enjoy the feeling that you were more directly interacting with HTTP.